# Lagrange multipliers/dual problem: A simple worked example for max(2-x^2) s.t. x=1

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to derive the dual problem of a very simple example of a Lagrange multiplier (note: please correct my terminology if it's off).

This isn't homework, I've just picked the example off some slides somewhere and am trying to solve it to understand the process. I haven't found many simple examples that work through the process from beginning to end. I feel like I'm close to understanding the process, there's just some minor mistakes I'm making where I don't connect what I see in various presentations of the technique to what I'm trying to do here.

$$f_0(x) = \max_x (2-x^2) \,\, \text{ s.t.: } \,\,\, x=1$$

Easy enough, answer must be 1 from visual inspection. So we set up the Lagrange multiplier:

$$g(x) = x-1$$
$$L(x,\lambda) = f_0(x)-\lambda g(x)$$
$$L(x,\lambda) = (2-x^2)-\lambda(x-1)$$
$$L(x,\lambda) = 2-\lambda-x^2-\lambda x$$

Now, if I understand correct, I want to set the terms with x in them to zero to get the dual problem (I think I go off track here). In the lectures I've watched, this is where we factor out x and set the x terms equal to zero, otherwise that part of the equation would go to infinity.

$$g(\lambda) = \min_{\lambda} \left[ 2-\lambda+( -x-\lambda)x\right]$$
$$\begin{cases}2-\lambda & (-x-\lambda)=0 \\ \infty & otherwise \end{cases}$$

Now I try to say $\lambda = -x$, that gives me a dual problem that comes out badly:
$$g(\lambda)= \min_{\lambda} (2-\lambda)$$ 
Given the constraints:
$$\lambda > 0$$
$$\lambda = -x$$

This is where it all breaks down for me. I missed something simple there. I know I'm supposed to derive the vectors of partial derivatives at some point, and I haven't yet, I know I'm doing something wrong there. And I don't know what to do to factor out the x properly.

Can someone help me work through this simple example. I'm sure things will click once I get through at least one concrete example beginning to end.

Comment: I flipped my max/min's, corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dual function
$$g(\lambda) := \min_{\lambda} \left[ 2-\lambda+( -x-\lambda)x\right]
$$
is better written
$$
h(\lambda) := \max_{x} \left[ 2-\lambda+x( \lambda - x)\right]\tag1
$$
because (a) you've used $g$ already for $g(x)=x-1$, and (b) you should be maximizing over $x$, not minimizing over $\lambda$, and (c) you have a sign wrong in your simplification.

That said, you want to maximize the quantity in square brackets in (1) over $x$, treating $\lambda$ as fixed.  The way to maximize over $x$ is to use calculus, or to complete the square. If we do that, we find the max occurs at $x=\lambda/2$. This means that (1) simplifies to
$$
h(\lambda) = 2 - \lambda +{\lambda^2\over 4},\tag2
$$
so the dual problem is now: minimize $h(\lambda)$ over all $\lambda$. It's minimized at $\lambda=2$, and the value of $h$ there is $1$.

(I'm not clear on what is meant by 'factoring out $x$' or 'setting the $x$ terms to zero', unless we're talking about simplifying $h$ so that $x$ no longer appears. In the approach that you took, $x$ still appears in your constraint $\lambda=-x$.)

Comment: Ah, duh, dumb mistake, I see it now. Thank you! The constraints on the dual problem then become what though? The way I understood it, the constraints on lambda, other than lambda >0, depends on the x(lambda - x) term. And that confuses me still.

Comment: You might be thinking of the Wolfe dual problem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfe_duality ) which recasts the Lagrangian dual problem in this case as "minize $2-\lambda + x(\lambda -x)$ over $x$ AND $\lambda$, subject to $\lambda >0$ and $\lambda - 2x=0$". But this second constraint, which sets the gradient of $2-\lambda + x(\lambda-x)$ to zero, has already popped out in the above approach; and we used up that constraint to get the final form (2). In the above approach (which isn't the Wolfe approach), there remains just the constraint $\lambda>0$.

Comment: ... and BTW I think if your constraint in the original problem is an equality constraint ($x=1$), this translates to no constraint on the sign of the corresponding $\lambda$.